# Is there a way to simulate / slow down asset loading in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets

I want to test a site in Rails as if it had a very slow internet connection, the js loads in 10 seconds after the page for example.

Is there a way to slow down the url for this for example:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

All Google results cover slow load page times and how to speed them up, I'm finding it quite hard to Google how to do this.

Comment: Use Chrome Dev Tools to throttle your connection. In the Network tab there's a tiny section with "No Throttling". Choose "Slow 3G".

Comment: @razvans suggestion of doing this in the client is good. Doing this on the server side is going to be a lot more complex. How assets are served depends on the environment and toolset (sprockets, webpacker, whatever Rails 7 throws at you).

Comment: @max Oh, didn't think this could also be a server side thing.

Comment: @razvans its at least theoretically possible - I'm not actually sure how to do it but you could for example use a proxy or tunnel with a slowdown. If we are talking something thats served by Rack you can put a peice of middleware in the way that just sleeps for a bit before doing its job.

Comment: Webpack-devserver apparently also takes middleware. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverdevmiddleware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with this answer in the comment - [Is there a way to simulate / slow down asset loading in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70334320/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-slow-down-asset-loading-in-rails#comment124330061_70334320) - that was super helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On what device?

Simulate the situation I would say.

- Connect the device to your phone as a hotspot and then choose the lowest speed on your phone for that device.
- Visit ( GET ) via opera browser on vpn that is far from your location and secured, this slows down dramatically.
- Visit your website via Tor browser
- Do the 3 above at the same time.

Bonus: Go to starbucks, get the wi-fi connection and go sit as far as possible with losing basic connection.